# Un reto muy poco usual

Tags: javascript

Haber tengo el caso de que un cliente me a pedido que en una de sus paginas le agregue un popUp con un js incrustado en dicho popUp y al cargar la pagina en un botón cualquiera yo llamo al popUp sin novedad (todo bien hasta aqui), el problema sucede que cuando cierro el popUp por error y quiero volverlo a abrir este me carga, me carga sin el script de js por que el DOM ya ha cargado todos los archivos; lo que Yo he hecho es tratar de que la pagina se recargue sin por error alguien le da a cerrar con el siguiente código:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
const x = document.querySelector(".eicon-close");

x.addEventListener('click', _ => { // el _ es para indicar la ausencia de parametros
location.reload();});)};
```

donde ".eicon-close" en una X llamada desde font awesome y que estoy tratando de manipularla. Solo este codigo funciona cuanya se llama por primera vez el popUp pero antes no. Como le harían ustedes para que funcione?
Yo ya he intentado hasta con

```
function recarga(){
const l = document.querySelector(".eicon-close")
l.setAttribute("onCLick", "document.location.reload(true)")}

if (document.addEventListener){
  window.addEventListener('load',recarga(),false);
} else {
    window.attachEvent('onload',recarga());
}
```

Y nada que me resulta. Un saludo...

Comment: El titulo debe ser descriptivo del problema.. que tal "como cargar un js en un popup una vez que se cargo la pagina"

Comment: Gracias por la orientación

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] para hacer las modificaciones correspondientes. Lee [ask].

Comment: ¿Cuál es el reto *poco usual*? En tu pregunta planteas una situación que es de lo más usual en programación Web.

Comment: Eso lo dirás tu que eres experto en la materia cierto? la cuestión es puedes colaborarme con el código a como solucionarlo? de así sera un gracias por adelantado, en su defecto, gracias por la critica entonces.

Comment: Era de suponerlo @MauricioContreras criticas sin saber la respuesta acertada. La cuestión no es criticar amigo mio, es ayudar y solucionar y si no puedes demostrar valia es mejor quedar callado.